# The internal energy of a real gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas, gas

I apologise in advance, but I am asking for clarification.

I learnt from a first year undergraduate physics book that in the case of ideal monatomic gases, the internal energy is given by $E_{int} = n \times C_V \times T$. But this represents the rms kinetic energy of a molecule.

**Q1**. In the real gases I think the potential energy should contribute. I read a book called *Physical Chemistry* by Atkins, and he says

> In thermodynamics, the total energy of a system is called its internal
> energy, U. The internal energy is the total kinetic and potential
> energy of the molecules in the system.

Is another term representing electrical (and perhaps gravitational?) potential energy there?

**Q2**. What if the gas is diatomic? Halliday, in his book Fundamentals of Physics, says

> Let us also assume that the internal energy Eint is the sum of the
> translational kinetic energies of the atoms. **(Quantum theory disallows**
> **rotational kinetic energy for individual atoms.)**

What is this actually about?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential energy they are talking about here is the energy of interaction between the molecules which is usually approximated by the so-called Leonard-Jones 6-12 potential.  Because of this, for a real gas, the internal energy is a function of both temperature and specific volume, given by $$dU=nC_vdT-\left[P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\right]dV$$Note that, for an ideal gas, whose equation of state is such that pressure is directly proportional to temperature at constant volume, the 2nd term vanishes, and U is a function only of T.  And, of course, at low pressures, a real gas approaches ideal gas behavior.